# What is the best way to left align radio buttons on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment

I have a bunch of radio buttons, and I have a

```
<br/>
```

after each one and they all seem to horizontal align center (even if I put some CSS that says left align).

Here is the CSS,

```
.radioLeft
{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <input checked="checked" class="radioLeft"  name="CalendarType" value="1" type="radio"><b>Person </b>(False) <br>
 <input checked="checked" class="radioLeft"  name="CalendarType" value="2" type="radio"><b>Event </b>(False) <br>
 <input checked="checked" class="radioLeft"  name="CalendarType" value="3" type="radio"><b>Release</b>(False) <br>
```

Comment: Ooohh, oohh, is it by using `<table>`? :-)

Comment: A bit more HTML so I can put it in http://jsfiddle.net/d9Nvk/

Comment: @Fred: It seems there's a parent element with `text-align: center`, so you'll probably have to reset that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't apply this style to the radios but to the container they are on, in that case you can add a div:

```
<div class="radioLeft">
  <input checked="checked" name="CalendarType" value="1" type="radio"><b>Person </b>(False) <br>
   <input checked="checked" name="CalendarType" value="2" type="radio"><b>Event </b>(False) <br>
   <input checked="checked"  name="CalendarType" value="3" type="radio"><b>Release</b>(False) <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with the following CSS style.

```
.radioLeft input{
    text-align: left;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: +1 for `display: inline` - keeps things (a little) simpler. You could also use `inline-block` if things play up. Welcome to SO :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the alignment of the container that surrounds them.

Answer (score 0):

You try to add a CSS property that only applies to block-level elements (like `div`) to an inline element (`input`).  This won't work; you need to create a block-level element (I chose to use `label` and make it block-level using CSS, but that's just for semantics) and use it to contain each label.

Try wrapping each in a `label` with class `.radioLeft`, remove that class from the inputs, and then add this CSS:

```
.radioLeft {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

For example,

```
<label class="radioLeft"><input type="radio"><b>Person</b>(False)</label>
```